# Can't connect to VMs via ssh from Windows 11 PC after it's hard stop

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I've had an issue with my laptop network adapter (suddenly lost all connection to WIFI and Bluetooth and under the Device Manager, the Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz there was and exclamation mark and device couldn't be started properly). I've done hard power off with pressing power button for 5-10 sec) and restart. Since then I am no able to connect via ssh.

I've a couple of Linux virtual machines on Virtual Box, trying to connect with powershell/cmd (I'm on win 11) to one with a password auth (like I previously did):

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.1p1, LibreSSL 3.6.1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/eugen/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.56.102 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\eugen/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\eugen/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.102 [192.168.56.102] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0344E950
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.102 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.102 port 22: Connection timed out
```

And also via MobaXterm:

```
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 9: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.56.102 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/EVIL/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/EVIL/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.102 [192.168.56.102] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.102 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.102 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Also failed to connect to another Linux VM with a ssh-key (like I previously did):

```
PS C:\Users\eugen> ssh -vvv -i 'C:\Users\eugen\.ssh\id_rsa-uvm' serveru@192.168.56.101
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.1p1, LibreSSL 3.6.1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/eugen/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.56.101 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\eugen/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\eugen/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.101 [192.168.56.101] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:03673B30
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.101 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.101 port 22: Connection timed out
```

And now I got the exact same issue on another Win 11 Pro Laptop with Hyper-V VM (it's also happened after it's hard stop with holding power button for a while)

I tried to reinstall OpenSSH and restart it's services on Windows.

However, I'm able to establish ssh connection with my localhost (with OpenSSH server installed) and other fully external servers with no problem, so it seems ssh is working, but not with my "host-only" network VM's

```
`PS C:\Users\eugen> ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.1p1, LibreSSL 3.6.1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/eugen/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\eugen/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\eugen/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup localhost:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.`
```

```
    ssh ip172-19-0-26-cfu1id63tccg00bkr4l0@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
The authenticity of host 'direct.labs.play-with-docker.com (40.76.55.146)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:vCbhEjmYQhtNzuuuh7TmGAPfe9T+JdGnGaVquQJUphY.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'direct.labs.play-with-docker.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Connecting to 52.188.144.191:8022
###############################################################
#                          WARNING!!!!                        #
# This is a sandbox environment. Using personal credentials   #
# is HIGHLY! discouraged. Any consequences of doing so are    #
# completely the user's responsibilites.                      #
#                                                             #
# The PWD team.                                               #
###############################################################
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.18 ~
```

UPDATE: It's working after creating a new network and assigning a new IP addresses to both VM's in Network tool (at least in Virtual Box)

Comment: I'm seeing a similar error connecting to my Windows 11 PC: debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001A494EB0DD0